# When to use Google "Application Licensing"?

Tags: android, google-play

When should we use Google Play's service Application Licensing?

Is this a new mechanism against cracked apps on Android?

When should I recommend my clients to use this service? I have read the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/index.html), but it did not answer to my queries.

I first thought that this is a mechanism for multimedia-selling apps only, but now I see I was wrong.

If anyone used this service, please tell me why you used it.

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404383/android-lvl-reasonable/9405447#9405447) helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When should we use Google Play's service Application Licensing?

When you have an application that you fear will be pirated, and sold/modified without your permission.

> Is this a new mechanism against cracked apps on Android?

This system itself has been cracked. Application Licensing uses the [LVL](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/overview.html) library. [AntiLVL](http://androidcracking.blogspot.com/p/antilvl_01.html) can crack it.

It's best to implement this in addition to your [own authentication methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html)(Cntrl+F for "Guidelines for custom policies".